# Magento - How to call a phtml template file from the URL

Tags: magento, php

The question pretty much says it all. I have a store locator application. Which dynamically produces a URL like:

```
http://www.XXXX.com/storelocator/index/viewstore/id/XXX
```

And I have also the template file in right directory:

```
package/template/storelocator/view_store.phtml
```

Also the block in:

```
app/code/local/COMPANY/Storelocator
```

When I click on the ID that is generated by the Javascript, it returns a 404 error. So obviously the template file is not loading. But I am not sure what is causing the issue. Can someone give me some idea.

Answer (score 1):

have you assign your template file in layout file if not try to assign your block in layout file.

```
<storelocator_index_viewstore>
 <block type="Storelocator/Storelocator" template="storelocator/view_store.phtml"></block>
</storelocator_index_viewstore>
```

This way when your action is call magento render this block and call your phtml file